# maximum no of android virtual devices on a pc

Tags: android

How many android virtual devices can run simultaneously on a PC.
Does it differ with configuration of the pc?

Comment: AFAIK, the only limit is the amount of RAM. Things might get rather sluggish from a CPU standpoint as well. And, due to the use of ports for telnet daemons, there's a mathematical limit of around 13,500, though you should run out of PC capacity long before then. However, it's possible there is some other hard-coded limit of which I am unaware.

Comment: @CommonsWare in the emulator doce it says : The console port number must be an even integer between 5554 and 5584, inclusive. <port>+1 must also be free and will be reserved for ADB ..

Comment: @StinePike: Really? Well, that will set the maximum number of emulators to be 16 (assuming that I am interpreting "inclusive" correctly). I had not realized that limit was there -- thanks!

Comment: yes now I am sure .. to write in details I had to post in answer. also pointed the links

Answer (score 7):

according to the android emulator doc [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

> The console port number must be an even integer between 5554 and 5584,
>   inclusive. +1 must also be free and will be reserved for ADB.

also in another doc [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

> An emulator instance occupies a pair of adjacent ports: a console port
>   and an adb port. The port numbers differ by 1, with the adb port
>   having the higher port number. The console of the first emulator
>   instance running on a given machine uses console port 5554 and adb
>   port 5555. Subsequent instances use port numbers increasing by two —
>   for example, 5556/5557, 5558/5559, and so on. Up to 16 concurrent
>   emulator instances can run a console facility.

so we can say that we can start at most 16 emulator.

Comment: Nice theoretical answer. I thought to answer it like "it depends on your ram". But it seems even with infinite ram you can't create more than 16. +10.