# What is the max number of Android emulators/port range that is supported to be run in one computer

Tags: android, android-emulator

Based on this documentation, one can run upto 64 emulators on even ports from 5554 to 5682

```
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline
The default value is 5554 for the first virtual device instance running on the your machine. A virtual device normally occupies a pair of adjacent ports: a console port and an adb port. The console of the first virtual device running on a particular machine uses console port 5554 and adb port 5555. Subsequent instances use port numbers increasing by two — for example, 5556/5557, 5558/5559, and so on. The range is 5554 to 5682, allowing for 64 concurrent virtual devices.
```

But emulator cli's help says differently

```
emulator -help-port
  at startup, the emulator tries to bind its control console at a free port  starting from 5554, in increments of two (i.e. 5554, then 5556, 5558, etc..)  this allows several emulator instances to run concurrently on the same  machine, each one using a different console port number.
  use '-port <port>' to force an emulator instance to use a given console port
  note that <port> must be an *even* integer between 5554 and 5584 included.  <port>+1 must also be free and will be reserved for ADB. if any of these  ports is already used, the emulator will fail to start.
```

When I run an emulator on a port outside of 5584, I get this warning

```
emulator: Requested console port 5632: Inferring adb port 5633.
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5633) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator.
```

Though adb's documentation says this https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#notlisted, I'm able to list devices running outside of 5584.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5590 device
emulator-5690 device
```

I'm confused.  Though running an emulator outside of 5584 works for me, is it supported? Which documentation should I refer?

Comment: Another stackoverflow post lead me to this [file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+blame/master/adb/transport_local.cpp) looking at a recent [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/25173c808a25ebe30f40b2337d8c87e2ea03e9e1) it appears they aren't limiting anymore so maybe the documentation is out of date.

Comment: also in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549650/maximum-no-of-android-virtual-devices-on-a-pc) the quoted "16 concurrent emulator instances" is no longer present in the linked docs.